# Flip sprite using Flutter Flame

Tags: flutter, game-engine, flame

I'm toying around with Flame game engine and am finding it difficult to flip the sprite. Most game engines/libraries allow you to do this by multiplying the x scale by -1. However, this does not work with the spritesheet/spriteanimation classes' size variable. What is considered the proper way to flip a sprite in flutter flame?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update for Flame >v1.4.0:**

Any component that extends `PositionComponent` (which all of the ones you listed do) you can use the `flipHorizontally()` and `flipVertically()` methods to flip your components.

**Old answer:**

On any component that extends `PositionComponent` (which all of the ones you listed do) you can just set `renderFlipX = true` or `renderFlipY = true` on the component and it will render flipped.

If you want to do this on a pure sprite, which doesn't seem like what you want to do but I'll mention it here anyways, you have to override the `render` method and flip the canvas before calling `super` and then restore it afterwards.

Comment: update: flame v1.4.0 uses flipHorizontally() and flipVertically() for PositionComponent and SpriteAnimationComponent classes

Comment: Can this be animated like flipping a playing card over?

Comment: You can create a ScaleEffect that goes from Vector2(1.1) to Vector2(-1,1);, a flip is really just negative scaling.

Comment: Can you elaborate on: `If you want to do this on a pure sprite, which doesn't seem like what you want to do but I'll mention it here anyways, you have to override the render method and flip the canvas before calling super and then restore it afterwards.`. How is this done?

Comment: @gotnull firstly, are you sure that is what you want to do? If you're using a SpriteComponent you have use the flip methods mentioned above.

Comment: @spydon: I ended up using a `positionAnchor` to achieve what I wanted to achieve when flipping the sprite.